# Server file read/write concurrency issue

Tags: php, apache

I have a web-service serving from a MySQL database. I would like to create cache file to improve the performance. The idea is once a while we read data from DB and generate a text file. My question is:

What if a client-side user is accessing the file while we are generating it?

We are using LAMP. In PHP there is flock() handles concurrency problem, but my understanding is that it's only for when 2 PHP processes accessing the file simultaneously. Our case is different.

I don't know whether this will cause issues at all. If so, how can I prevent it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use locking; 
if your cachefile is /tmp/cache.txt then you should always regenerate the cache to /tmp/cache2.txt and then do a

```
mv /tmp/cache2.txt /tmp/cache.txt
```

or

```
rename('/tmp/cache2.txt','/tmp/cache.txt')
```

the mv/rename operation is atomic if it happens inside the same filesystem; no locking needed

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of optimisation options here;

1) Are you using the [MySQL queryCache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) - that can take a huge load off the database to start with.

2) You could pull the file through a web proxy like squid (or Apache configured as a reverse caching proxy). I do this all the time and it's a really handy technique - generate the file by fetching it from a url using wget for example (that way you can have it in a cron job). The web proxy takes care of either delivering the same file that was there before, or regenerating it if needs be.

3) You don't want to be rolling your own file locking solution in this scenario.

Depending on your scenario, you could also consider cacheing pages in something like memcache which is fantastic for high traffic scenarios, but possibly beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use A -> B switching to avoid this issue.

E.g. : Let there be two copies of this cache file A and B, program should read these via a symlink, C.

When program is building the cache, it would modify the file that is not "current" I.e. if C link to A, update B. Once update is complete, switch symlink to B.

next time, update A and switch symlink to A once update is complete.

this way clients would never read a file while it is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

When a client-side access the file, it reads it as it is in that moment.
flock() is for when 2 PHP processes accessing the file simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

- While generating the new text file, save it to a temporary file (cache.tmp), that way the old file (cache.txt) is being accessed like before.
- When generation is done, delete the old file and rename the new file
- To avoid problems during that short period of time, your code should check wether cache.txt exists and retry for a short period of time.

Trivial but that should do the trick