# Access csv file using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am saving tick data to a csv file.

this file is gets continuously accessed by this function.

I want to access the data in this file and modify it in different python script.

If I try to access the same csv file in another script, then after sometime I get `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError`

so what is the correct way to access the `tick_data.csv` file in another script?
.

```
    def on_message(ws, tick):
            ltp = (tick[0]['ltp'])
            token = (tick[0]['tk'])
            filename = r'my_folder/tick_data.csv'
            df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=[0])
            df.loc[df.token == token, 'ltp'] = ltp
            df.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: you are probably facing a "race condition". df.to_csv will empty the file first, then write into it. if that happens at the same time your other script tries to read the file, it will get an empty file. Its a concept of "thread safety" where you should not modify something while another is trying to read it. so if you have 2 scripts reading and modifying at the same time a file is not the best choice for this.

Comment: ok. thank you for the information. so what is better choice?

Comment: we dont have enough information, it depends on what you want to do and how much control you have over the systems. how technical you want to get and what your limitations are.. check this answer for an easy fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473466/1310093

Comment: I read online about this and found that sqlite also dont support this type of operations, Are there any other databases which support concurrent access?                                 This is what I think : save content of tick_data file to database, create another csv file and copy then modified content from database to newly created csv file

Comment: sqlite should work for concurrent access. its just not very fast. but if your not doing thousands of operations a second it will work

Comment: thank you for the help, i will try this.

Comment: btw, if you dont need a file, i suggest just using sqlite directly without the copy to csv part. and if you did need a csv at some point, just create a script to write to csv when you need it